# Unique expression of a tensor as sum of two other tensors.

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, differential-geometry, tensors, multilinear-algebra

Given a covariant tensor $\alpha$, how do I prove that it has a *unique expression* of form $\alpha = \beta + \gamma$ where $\beta$ is alternating and $A\gamma = 0, A$ being the alternation of $\gamma$?

Currently I'm considering $\alpha = \beta$ when $\alpha$ is alternating and $\beta = A\alpha$ in general with $\gamma =$ Sym$\alpha$. Am I on the right track?

Another approach I'm considering is: take $\beta$ to be the linear combination of the basis elements of the alternating subspace and $\gamma$ to be the linear combinations of the elements in the basis of $T^r(V)$ but not in the basis of the alternating subspace.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is the alternating map, then you can prove it is a projection, because $A^2=A$. For you to have this, it is necessary to have the $1/k!$ factor in the alternation.

Let's work on a single vector space, $V$, which is real and $n$ dimensional. Let $T^*(V)$ be the covariant tensor algebra of $V$ (the same is true for contravariant tensors too, though), which is a graded algebra $$ T^*(V)=\oplus_{i=0}^\infty T^{0,i}(V), $$ where $T^{0,k}(V)$ is the space of $k$th order covariant tensors.

If $A$ is defined as $$ A=\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{\sigma}\text{sgn}(\sigma)P_\sigma, $$ where $k$ is the grade of the subspace of $T^*(V)$ $A$ acts upon, then $A$ will be a projection.

It is a well known result from linear algebra, that a projection operator splits a vector space into the direct sum $$ V=\text{Im}(P)\oplus\ker(P), $$ where $P$ is a projection, with $P$ being the projection onto $\text{Im}(P)$ and $1-P$ being the projection onto $\ker(P)$.

This is unique, because the direct sum decomposition is unique and because of $P^2=P$.

Now if $\omega\in T^{0,k}(V)$, a $k$th order covariant tensor, then we have $$ \omega=A\omega+(1-A)\omega, $$ which satisfies your requirements and is unique by the uniqueness of the direct sum decomposition.

(Of course, the direct sum decomposition is $$ T^{0,k}(V)=\Lambda^k(V^*)\oplus N^k, $$ where $N^k=\ker(A)$.)

*Note:* You approach with $\text{Sym}(\omega)$ would not work, because it is true only for second order tensors that $T^{0,2}=\Lambda^2(V^*)\oplus S^2(V^*)$. The symmetry properties of higher order tensors are more complicated, because only for second order tensors do we *only* have *total* symmetry or antisymmetry. For a higher order tensor, it is possible that it is symmetric only under the exchange of say *two* arguments. Then said tensor is **not** symmetric, but the alternating map will still kill it. The subspace $N^k$ in my approach is precisely the space of all $k$th order covariant tensors that *have at least one symmetric pair of arguments*.

Answer (score 0):

> Currently I'm considering $\alpha = \beta$ when $\alpha$ is alternating and $\beta = A\alpha$ in general with $\gamma =$ Sym$\alpha$. Am I on the right track?

Nearly. Instead of taking $\gamma =\mathrm{Sym}\alpha$ just take $\gamma=\alpha-\beta$ or in other words $\gamma=\alpha-A\alpha$. Then we automatically have $\alpha=\beta+\gamma$, and we have $A\gamma=A(\alpha-A\alpha)=A\alpha-AA\alpha=A\alpha-A\alpha=0$, which is what we wanted.